# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Date as Numerical Representation

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

Does anyone know if there is a way to get a number representation of a date, the same way DB2 does theirs?

https://www.ibm.com/docs/pl/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-days

```
SELECT 
POSTING_DATE,
DAYS(POSTING_DATE) AS NUMBER_REPRESENTATIOn
FROM core.env
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAM6T.png)

I've been searching but, cannot seem to find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is a very useful [REFERENCE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/#table2) into formatting MS SQL dates from a date field.

Comment: Thank you for this, I did come across this and it is a very helpful document but, I couldn't find the conversion I needed.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please see the image.

Comment: It should be a number like a large integer. A UTC representation of the date value. I'm not dealing with any time stamps just dates.

Comment: Here is a note from the DB2 documentation. Hope this helps: For each invocation of the DAYS function in this SELECT statement, the result is 731217.

When the input argument contains a time zone, the result is determined from the UTC representation of the input value. The string representations of a timestamp with a time zone in the SELECT statement all have the same UTC representation: 2003-01-02-20.00.00.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken .. You're just trying to get the number of days between two dates?  Your question is confusing, because your sample query doesn't match the format of your example images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/pl/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-days) seemed pretty clear, you just have to translate the formula to use T-SQL syntax (where we measure the number of days between two dates using [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)):

```
DECLARE @d date = '20220808';

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '00010101', @d) + 1;
```

Result:

> 738,375

Comment: FANTASTIC!!! You are are gentleman and a scholar :-)